# Is there a Vue.js equivalent to Angular's named templates?

Tags: angular, vue.js

Consider this angular code:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="someCondition; else spinner">
    Show Data
</ng-container>

<ng-template #spinner>
    Show Spinner
</ng-template>
```

**Is there a vue.js equivalent with `<template>`** ?

The main goal is to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Note to the downvoter: At least have the decency to explain yourself. This is not helpful 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic Vue approach is to simply extract the duplicating part into a separate component. That's what i would do.

However, you can also consider [createReusableTemplate](https://vueuse.org/core/createReusableTemplate/) from VueUse. It has a syntax very similar to your example.